# CupertinoAlertDialog with TextFIeld

Tags: flutter

How to add a TextField inside the Cupertino dialog. I try this code below, but didn't work :

```
showDialog<bool>(
    context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext,
    builder: (context) {
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text('Tambah baru'),
        content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Nama"),
            ),
        ],
        ),
    );
    },
);
```

The error said : "TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor."

Comment: wrap your TextFiled in Card Widget - Card(
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Nama"),
                                ),
                              ),

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This Should Solve the Issue:

```
showDialog<bool>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text('Tambah baru'),
      content: Card(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Nama",
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade50
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: You can use a `CupertinoTextField` instead of a `Card` for a complete iOS look.

Answer (score 2):

you can create like this

```
await showDialog<bool>(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                        actions: [
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Get.back();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Cancel",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              )),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (controller
                                  .groupNameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                Get.back();
                              } else {
                                cheryToast(context,
                                    msg: 'Please Select Group name');
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Create Group",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        title: Text('Group Name'),
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.h,
                            ),
                            CupertinoTextField(
                              controller: controller.groupNameController,
                              placeholder: "Enter Group Name",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
```